# How to use multiple rspec_helpers

Tags: ruby, rspec

We are experimenting with adding integration tests with rspec into our workflow, and are experimenting the following folder structure:

```
.
├── spec #unit tests
├── spec-integration #e2e tests
```

When I run the e2e tests with `bundle exec rspec SPECS=spec-integration`, the `--require spec_helper` from `.rspec` automatically goes to `spec/spec_helper`. This makes sense and expected, but we don't want to use the spec_helper from the unit tests, we want to use another one for integration tests.

How do I tell rspec to go to `spec-integration/spec_handler` instead of `spec/spec_handler` as a default?

(Edit/PS: Comments from a folder architecture or suggestions on a better way to design this are also welcome, as we are pretty new to the Ruby ecosystem)

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a rails app? I think there are rails conventions about how to organize your spec folder (pretty sure it is usually a single spec folder)

Comment: Using the `--require` option is somewhat of a code smell as each spec should run on its own regardless of the spec suite configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override that by specifying `--options` command line flag. ([ref](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files))

```
bundle exec rspec --default-path spec-integration --options spec_handler
```

Also, when you use `--default-path`, you can have a `spec-integration/spec_helper.rb` and it will use that(because of `--require spec_helper` in `.rspec`).

(This is not working for me on rspec 3.9 though - `bundle exec rspec SPECS=spec-integration`.)

Coming to the folder structure part, I would keep integration specs in a sub-folder inside `spec`. Both unit and integration specs can have their own helper files and `spec/spec_helper` can have common configuration.